# How can I use sling object in a java class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, sling

How can I use sling object in a java class(Servlet), I can use that in a jsp file. Can we use that in a java file.
Like this  in a Java class:

```
sling.getService(LoginServiceClient.class)
```

Comment: Are you talking about [Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/site/index.html) here? Or maybe Spring?

Comment: That's definitely Apache Sling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive that you're trying to get OSGi service (`LoginServiceClient`) in some servlet. If your servlet is also managed by the OSGi (so it's annoted with `@Component` annotation), then you can use dependency injection to get any service you want:

```
@Component(immediate = true)
@Service
@Properties({
    @Property(name = ServletResolverConstants.SLING_SERVLET_PATHS, value = "/my/servlet/path"),
    @Property(name = ServletResolverConstants.SLING_SERVLET_METHODS, value = { HttpConstants.METHOD_GET })
})

public class MyServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
    @Reference
    LoginServiceClient loginServiceClient;
...
}
```

All these annotations are handled by the [Maven SCR plugin](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html).